# DropboxServerException: 400 Bad Request (Expected 'root' to be 'dropbox', 'sandbox', or 'auto'; got "autonull")

Tags: android, dropbox

I am using Dropbox SDK in Android application development.

I list the entries of such a directory under the root directory like this:

```
entries = mDBApi.metadata(path, 2000, null, true, null);
```

and sometimes I get this exception, and sometimes it works very well:

```
DropboxServerException (nginx): 400 Bad Request (Expected 'root' to be 'dropbox', 'sandbox', or 'auto'; got "autonull")
    at com.dropbox.client2.RESTUtility.parseAsJSON(RESTUtility.java:265)
    at com.dropbox.client2.RESTUtility.execute(RESTUtility.java:415)
    at com.dropbox.client2.RESTUtility.execute(RESTUtility.java:339)
    at com.dropbox.client2.RESTUtility.streamRequest(RESTUtility.java:194)
    at com.dropbox.client2.RESTUtility.request(RESTUtility.java:124)
    at com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI.metadata(DropboxAPI.java:1730)
```

I don't understand what's the autonull? and from where it came from.

please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "auto" part is the "root" that the SDK supplies to the API, and "auto" is a valid value that tells the API to determine the correct root based on the app key.

In the actual API call, the root comes just before the path in the actual HTTP request, so it seems "autonull" is the concatenation of your root and your path. That is, your `path` is apparently null, when it should be some string that starts with "/". The "/" at the beginning of your path would properly separate it from the root. You can see a sample of using the `metadata` method here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/android#listing